# Haskell - singleton and 'fromList'

Tags: haskell

What means the code below?

```
singleton 1 'a' == fromList [(1, 'a')]
```

Comment: You should mention what module you're importing. Also do you know how to browse library documentation on hackage? Do you know how to use GHCi to look at function types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`singleton` and `fromList` appear in several container modules.

Typically, `singleton` returns a container with a single element, and `fromList` returns a container with all of the elements from the list (modulo key duplication in mappings).

The example you give shows `singleton` taking 2 arguments, which implies that the container is a mapping (`Set`, `IntSet`, `HashMap`, etc...), and expects the key and value of the single element.  For mappings, `fromList` expects a list of key, value pairs.

The equality you show states that the container with a single element that maps the number `1` to the character `'a'` is the same whether it is constructed using `singleton`, or `fromList` with a single-element list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this is from an [IntMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.1.0/doc/html/Data-IntMap.html).  Both `singleton` and `fromList` reside there.  The data structure is basically an efficient implementation of a map which goes from integers to values based on patricia trees.

Comment: Could also be `Data.Map`. The interfaces are very similar.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, should have noted that, but the question is underspecified by the OP, so to figure out which it is he needs top look at the top of his source file..

Comment: Yes, I just thought it should be mentioned. Aside, your link goes to `containers-0.1.0.1`, that's pretty ancient, I suggest pointing it to a newer version.

Comment: @DanielFischer yup, edited, it was the first implementation that showed up when I typed in intmap to hoogle..